# How to setup two different projects with different repositories in github using VScode?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Can anyone guide me how can i change repositories to commit directly from vs code? im currently working on two projects and i want to commit each project to their respective repositories, but vs code seemingly does'nt give an option to change repositories and keeps bugging me to upload on the wrong respository. It initializes  the repository on its own when it starts up and i cant change it after
Im fairly new to this whole github thing so please be considerate :))) Thanks for your help.
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to provide details about your workspace and folder structure, your git remote config, and what is the expected flow of steps/commands you want to do. A screenshot of the node modules changes and portion of code does not help.

Comment: Unrelated, you should not be committing your node_modules folder into your repo.